# Regex following the SEPA instructions

Tags: java, regex, java-17

I need a regex that follows the following rules

*SEPA functions according to the following instructions:


The full range of global language requirements (as defined in UTF-8) In particular, the Latin character set commonly used in international communication, as follows:*

- > a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I
  > J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- > / - ? : ( ) . , ' +
- > Spaces
- > Content must not start or end with a / and content must not contain //

The regex should work in java 17.

I have tried a myriad of regexes both my own and taken from other threads but they do not seem to work.

Comment: I would start with `"[\\p{Alnum} ?:().,'+-](?:/(?!/)|[\\p{Alnum} ?:().,'+-])*[\\p{Alnum} ?:().,'+-]"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Honestly, I don’t understand the “instructions”. Most notably “The full range of global language requirements” is not even a sentence. And it obviously contradicts (when trying to interpret it somehow) the subsequent “the Latin character set”, as the Latin character set is not “the full range”. Do you have a link to the source of this quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first 3 rules just list valid characters. That's trivially doable in regex: `[ a-zA-Z0-9/().,?'+-]` represents one character from the 'allowed' set (note that the dash has to be at the start or end, or needs to be backslash escaped, otherwise it's interpreted as providing a range, such as in `a-z`).

The last rule is a little bit trickier.

If your interest is to write code that is simple, fast, and easy to read, **do not** try to implement that last line with regexes. Simply:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {
  private static final Pattern VALID_CHARS = Pattern.compile(
  "[ a-zA-Z0-9/().,?'+-]*");

  public static boolean valid(String in) {
    return
      !in.startsWith("/") &&
      !in.endsWith("/") &&
      !in.contains("//") &&
      VALID_CHARS.matcher(in).matches();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("/123");
    test("ABC?.+");
    test("ABC?/.+");
    test("ABC?/.//+");
  }

  public static void test(String a) {
    System.out.println(a + ": " + valid(a));
  }
}
```

If you *must* do it as a single regex, oof. There are a few ways to go, but the most readable is probably to use negative lookahead.

```
private static final Pattern VALID_CHARS = Pattern.compile(
  "(?!/)([ a-zA-Z0-9().,?'+-]|/(?![^/]))*(?<!/)");
```

This says: Start of string, then fail if there's a slash, then a sequence of zero to many of either:

- Any of the valid characters other than slash
- a slash, but then fail if the char after is a slash
- Finally, look one back; if that is a slash, fail.

Replacing in the original example the regex with the above, you can get rid of the `contains,` startsWith`and`endsWith` conditions.

A few notes on the 'style' here:

- The regexes are designed to avoid all backslash escapes where possible. For example, `?` and `(` must be escaped in regexes normally, but not in `[]` blocks. Regexes are hard enough to read as is.
- One could just use `str.matches("^regex here$")` but there's an advantage to doing it just once: That regex string has to be parsed and 'compiled', and it saves a teensy tiny amount of time to do it just once. The maxim 'premature optimization is evil' is a good rule of thumb that should stop you when you are making your code more complex than it needs to be or make it harder to use or modify in the future. In this case, none of that applies: The code as is is just as easy, if not easier to read, and is easier to modify in the future.
- `matches` already scans for a complete match, thus, `^` and `$` (regex-ese for 'start of string' and 'end of string') aren't needed.

Comment: @user85421 answer edited to take that into account.

Comment: Small update to allow the use of spaces within the string, the first regEx must become like this: 
`[a-zA-Z0-9/().,?'+-, ]*`

Comment: Good eye, @Marco_Frost - I have edited the answer with your suggested update. One small error in yours, that `-` has to be escaped, or be at the start or end.

Answer (score -2):

Try :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9/\-\?\:\(\)\.\,\'\+\ ]+$
```

You can test it out in https://regex101.com/ which also gives a nice explanation of what is going on.

Comment: That misses the "Content must not start or end with a / and content must not contain //" part, doesn't it?

Comment: Also, holy backslash escapes batman. You do not need them - none of em. The only one that is dubiously required is to backslash escape the `-`, but if you stick it at the start or end, you don't need that either.